Given that $P\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ has a root $r$. Can we find a polynomial in $P$ with root $r^2$?
Suppose we know that a polynomial $p(x)$ with integer coefficients has an  root $r$ (not necessarily an integer).
Then we know that $\sqrt{r}$ will be a root of the polynomial $p(x^2)$ which still has integer coefficients.
But can we find a polynomial that we know will have $r^2$ as a root and still have integer coefficients? Clearly if we were given $p(x)$ the problem would become trivial, but can this be solved for a general $p(x)$?
$p(\sqrt{x})$ would have a root of $r^2$, however we cannot guarantee that $p(\sqrt{x})$ will be a polynomial at all.

How about $q(x) = x - r^2$?

No, we cannot. Let $p(x)=x-\sqrt{2}$. We know it has the root $r=\sqrt{2}$. Then $p(\sqrt{x})$ is indeed not a polynomial. Can you make precise what exactly you assume for the polynomial with root $r^2$?

A polynomial with coefficients where?

@PaulTanenbaum Apologies, I forgot to mention that the polynomial has integer coefficients.

@underflow I was supposing that we know nothing about $r$ or $p(x)$ and that the answer would be in terms of $p$ and $r$. For example $p(x-1)$ has the root $r+1$. Does this clarify my question?

@Sil I know that it will still be algebraic, but I was wondering whether we can establish a new polynomial (related to $p(x)$) that has the root $r^2$.

Look at the answer in the linked post.

I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order for it to reflect the question.

what it means for $r^2$ to be algebraic is that there is a polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ that has $r^2$ as a root, so how does Sil's link not answer your question?

$p(\sqrt{x})$ may not be a polynomial, but $g(x)=p(\sqrt{x})p(-\sqrt{x})$ is.

@Macavity Thank you. This is the answer I was looking for!
